# Self-homomorphisms of surface groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory

Let $X$ be a closed, orientable surface of genus at least 2, and let $\phi: \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(X)$ be a surjective homomorphism.  Is $\phi$ necessarily injective?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Surface groups are [Hopfian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group).  More generally, all [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite) groups are Hopfian -- see Theorem IV.4.10 in Lyndon and Schupp's book "Combinatorial Group Theory".

Comment: I knew I could count on you.  Should I just keep trying to prove it myself or is there a reference?

Comment: I gave a reference for a more general statement -- there's probably a more direct proof for surface groups, but the more general statement is extremely useful.  For the residual finiteness of surface groups, see Hempel's beautiful 1-page paper "Residual finiteness of surface groups".

Comment: And I should also point out that the proof in Lyndon and Schupp I referred to above is only one paragraph long and mostly self-contained.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but all *finitely generated* residually finite groups are Hopfian.

Comment: Good point Steve!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'll take a look at the references next time I give up. I clearly have a lot to learn about group theory.

Comment: The proof is easy enough to write in a comment.  Suppose g is in the kernel of a surjection $\phi:G\to G$ and let $q: G\to Q$ be a finite quotient with $q(g)\neq 1$.  Then it's easy to see that $q\circ\phi^n$ are all distinct maps $G\to Q$.  But there are only finitely many maps from a finitely generated group to a fixed finite group.